# Swift - Combine multiple discount types

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

so I've been playing around with [protocol witness types](https://nsscreencast.com/episodes/486-codable-witnesses-1), which are in essence concrete implementations of protocols. Say we have a protocol which discounts an item, returning a double.

Instead of this:

```swift
protocol Discountable {
    func discount() -> Double
}
```

One does this:

```swift
struct Discounting<A> {
    let discount: (A) -> Double
}
```

And, instead of conforming once a type to the `Discountable` protocol like this:

```swift
extension Double: Discountable {
    func discount() -> Double {
        return self * 0.9
    }
}
```

One can offer multiple concrete implementations for a type:

```swift
extension Discounting where A == Double {
    static let tenPercentOff = Self { amount in
        amount * 0.9
    }
    
    static let fiveDollarsOff = Self { amount in
        amount - 5
    }
}
```

However, I was wondering how one could *combine* multiple of these discounts. Here's my initial sketch:

```swift
static func combine(_ discounts: [Discounting<A>]) -> Discounting<A> {
    Discounting { (amount: A) -> Double in
        return discounts.reduce(0.0) { current, discount in
            // ??
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure what to put inside the reduce closure.

How can I combine multiple of these `Discounting` types into one?

Comment: I just read the linked article. It seems like you might be misunderstanding this pattern a little bit.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you think that – one of the authors of the article made a validation library around this pattern, which also implements a "combine" function: [swift-validations](https://github.com/lukeredpath/swift-validations#combining-validators). However, instead of combining validations, I want to combine discounts – such as combining a 10%-off discount and a 5-dollars-off discount from the example.

Comment: Okay, maybe not misunderstanding the _pattern_, but you are definitely misunderstanding what the type `Discounting` represents. Anyway, combining validators is a bit different from what you've got here, namely that the validators don't depend on each other - their order doesn't matter. OTOH, the order of the discounts matter - the result of each discount depend on the result of the previous one.

Comment: I reread the article, and sort of understood more of the use case. It seems like you want to apply discounts to different parts of an object as well (e.g. `shippingAmount` and `amount`)? Then I think using `(A) -> A` as the function type would be the best alternative design. See my edited answer. The design of `Discounting` right now doesn't support combining discounts. "someone else also implements a combine function with this pattern" isn't really a good argument here. This pattern isn't really related to whether you can implement a `combine` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this design, you cannot compose a list of `Discounting<A>`s for an arbitrary `A`.

A `Discounting<A>` represents a way to compute the price after a discount, given an `A` object. Note that this is a function of `A`, not a function of price. From the linked article, this type parameter `A` seems to represent the thing to which you are discounting.

So basically, the information that a `[Discounting<A>]` contains is a list of functions that, given a thing `A`, can give you the discounted price for them. As you can see, there is no room for "applying another discount". All you get after applying the first discount is the discounted price, but `Discounting` represents discounts on *things*, not prices. You need a *discounted* `A` object to apply the second discount.

If you had a `Discounting<Double>` however, composition is possible,

```
func combine(_ discounts: [Discounting<Double>]) -> Discounting<Double> {
    Discounting(discount: discounts.reduce({ $0 }, { compose($0, $1.discount) }))
}

func compose<T, U, V>(_ f1: @escaping (T) -> U, _ f2: @escaping (U) -> V) -> ((T) -> V) {
    { f2(f1($0)) }
}
```

To solve the problem for the general case, `Discounting<A>` could be redesigned as returning a discounted version of the input:

```
struct Discounting<A> {
    let discount: (A) -> A
}

// This is the "protocol witness" version of:
//
// protocol Discountable {
//     func discount() -> Self
// }
```

This way, you can also compose them with the same code that composes `Discounting<Double>`s that I showed above:

```
func combine<T>(_ discounts: [Discounting<T>]) -> Discounting<T> {
    Discounting(discount: discounts.reduce({ $0 }, { compose($0, $1.discount) }))
}
```

Example usage:

```
struct Purchase {
    var amount: Double
    var shippingAmount: Double
}

extension Discounting where A == Purchase {
    static let tenPercentOff: Self = .init { purchase in
        Purchase(amount: purchase.amount * 0.9, shippingAmount: purchase.shippingAmount)
    }

    static let tenPercentOffShipping: Self = .init { purchase in
        Purchase(amount: purchase.amount, shippingAmount: purchase.shippingAmount * 0.9)
    }
    
    static let fiveDollarsOff: Self = .init { purchase in
        Purchase(amount: purchase.amount - 5, shippingAmount: purchase.shippingAmount)
    }
}

let combinedDiscounts: Discounting<Purchase> = combine([.tenPercentOff, .fiveDollarsOff, .tenPercentOffShipping])
// Purchase(amount: 85.0, shippingAmount: 90.0)
print(combinedDiscounts.discount(Purchase(amount: 100, shippingAmount: 100)))
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you for the detailed answer – I was indeed looking at the computation `Discount` represents in a completely wrong way.

Comment: However, now that I changed the closure to `(A) -> (A)` I lose the ability to implement a `pullback` function, correct?

Comment: @PrayForTech Correct. However, if you can add another `(A) -> B` parameter to `pullback`, you can still technically write a function that changes the type in the `<>`. It’s not very useful though, because you can’t create a `Purchase` (`B`) from just one `Double` (`A`).